# Retrieving the number of ticket raises per group

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table (`my_tbl`) representing the history of ticket raises, and I'm attempting to retrieve the number of raises per `assigned_to_group` specifically for the month of December 2023. I want the result to display the distinct assigned_to_group values along with the corresponding count of raises.
The group ID is selected from within the same entity_id, and it should precede the raise, being the most recent one.

Here's the table structure and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE my_tbl (
    entity_id INT,
    nb_raise_c VARCHAR(255),
    assigned_to_group VARCHAR(255),
    time_c TIMESTAMP
);

INSERT INTO my_tbl (entity_id, nb_raise_c, assigned_to_group, time_c)
VALUES
(1, NULL, '10086',  '2023-01-11 15:51:20.021+01:00'),
(1, '0',  '10086',  '2023-01-11 15:51:20.021+01:00'),
(1, NULL, '435334', '2023-01-11 15:54:47.471+01:00'),
(1, NULL, '435334', '2023-01-11 15:54:47.471+01:00'),
(1, '1',  NULL,     '2023-08-29 16:01:39.135+02:00'),
(1, '2',  NULL,     '2023-09-26 15:02:00.968+02:00'),
(1, '3',  NULL,     '2023-12-19 10:52:31.812+01:00'),
(2, NULL, '45457',  '2023-11-28 15:51:20.021+01:00'),
(2, '0',  NULL,     '2023-11-28 16:53:20.021+01:00'),
(2, '1',  NULL,     '2023-11-30 18:58:20.021+01:00'),
(2, '2',  NULL,     '2023-12-02 07:10:28.021+01:00'),
(2, NULL, '36781',  '2023-12-04 07:10:28.021+01:00'),
(2, '3',  NULL,     '2023-12-05 07:10:28.021+01:00'),
(2, NULL, '45457',  '2023-12-06 07:10:28.021+01:00'),
(2, '4',  NULL,     '2023-12-07 07:10:28.021+01:00');
```

I've attempted the following SQL query, but it's not providing the expected result:

```
WITH ranked_groups AS (
    SELECT
        entity_id,
        nb_raise_c,
        assigned_to_group,
        time_c,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY entity_id, nb_raise_c ORDER BY time_c DESC) AS rnk
    FROM
        my_tbl
    WHERE
        nb_raise_c IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
    assigned_to_group,
    COUNT(nb_raise_c) AS num_relance
FROM
    ranked_groups
WHERE
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM time_c) = 12
    AND rnk = 1
GROUP BY
    assigned_to_group;
```

The current result is not as expected, showing null as the assigned_to_group and a count of 4. I would appreciate assistance in modifying the query to obtain the desired result, which should look like this:

| assigned_to_group | num_relance |
| --- | --- |
| 435334 | 1 |
| 45457 | 2 |
| 36781 | 1 |

db fiddle : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tVtJVEEqv1TuGzrZHvL8Sm/0

Comment: Hi - your required result doesn't seem to align with your sample data and your requirements. 435334 has no records in December so shouldn't appear in your results.  45457 has only 1 record in December so should only have a count of 1 in your results. Please can you clarify?

Comment: Hi the group 435334  is the most recent one in the history, so it's this group which received raise

Comment: when you rank groups partitioned by entity_id and nb_raise_c, then the designations to groups are not being contained in the same partitions as the raise_c. (Because the raise_c is null for them). They are even thrown away in the where clause of your CTE. So any further actions on this CTE-generated view, is going to result in group is null, and thus grouped to 4x group = null. See my answer below for sollution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short summary:

1. split in "raises" and "assignments to groups"
2. join those, to get all "assignments" per "raised entity" (assignment should be before or at the same time as the raise)
3. get the latest "raise", to determine the "group" for that "raise"
4. After that in the main query just simple grouping

in code:

```
with overview as (
    select 
        distinct on (a.entity_id, a.nb_raise_c) 
        a.entity_id, 
        a.nb_raise_c, 
        raising_time, 
        assigned_to_group 
    from (
        select 
            entity_id, 
            time_c as raising_time, 
            nb_raise_c 
        from 
            my_tbl 
        where 
            not nb_raise_c isnull
        ) a 
    left join (
        select 
            entity_id, 
            time_c as grouping_time, 
            assigned_to_group 
        from 
            my_tbl 
        where 
            not assigned_to_group isnull
        ) b 
    on 
        a.entity_id = b.entity_id 
        and raising_time >= grouping_time 
    order by 
        a.entity_id, 
        a.nb_raise_c, 
        grouping_time desc)

-- start Main

select 
    assigned_to_group, 
    count(*) 
from 
    overview 
where 
    EXTRACT(month FROM raising_time) = 12 
group by 
    assigned_to_group 
order by 
    assigned_to_group::bigint
```

| assigned_to_group | count |
| --- | --- |
| 36781 | 1 |
| 45457 | 2 |
| 435334 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tVtJVEEqv1TuGzrZHvL8Sm/1)